# Using dynamically created array of textboxes in php

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic-arrays

I have an array of textboxes which are dynamically created in PHP. I have 100 textboxes for CustomerIDs and 100 textboxes for CustomerEmails and besides that i have 100 update buttons.

Whenever i press the update button, it should update only that record of particular index.

The initial values of textboxes are coming from database.

The problem is that i don't know how to get the index of particular texbox.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$rowCounter = $rowCounter + 1;
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input name="txtRowCounter" id="txtRowCounter" type="text" value ="' . $rowCounter .'" /> </td>';  
echo '<td>' . $row['CustomerID'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><input name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" type="text" value ="' . $row['CustomerEmail1'] .'" /> </td>';    

echo '<td><input id="btnUpdate" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value = "Update" onclick="updateButton( document.getElementsByName(\'txtEmail\')[' . $rowCounter . '].value)" /> </td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple of options here.  You can create a new form for each record that's being submitted, but I think it would be easier to just give your button a name that includes your `$row['CustomerID']`.

For instance give your button a name of:

```
'... name="btnUpdate_"'.$row['CustomerID'].' value =...';
```

Then you can just parse it out on the processor end.